# Will shadowed binding be GCed?

Tags: garbage-collection, ocaml

Suppose I have this in an long run ml file:

```
let l = [1;2;3]

let l = [1;2;3;4]

let _ = ...
```

Will the first `l = [1;2;3]` be GCed sometime?

---

What if the code is like this:

```
let l = [1;2;3]

let l = [1;2;3;4]

let l = [1;2;3]

let _ = ...
```

There are three `l`. 1st is shadowed by 2nd, and then 2nd is shadowed by 3rd.

Are the following situations possible, since GC's schedule is not determined?

1. when reaching 3rd `l`, the GC has not collected the 1st `[1;2;3]`, so the same memory was reused or re-referenced
2. Immediately after 2nd `l`, GC collected 1st `[1;2;3]`, then the 3rd `l` create new memory for `[1;2;3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that depends on whether you still have references for it elsewhere - if l is the only reference, then yes, that reference is released on the second assignment, and will get GCed when appropriate.

---

lists are immutable in ocaml; list literals return new list instances.

from a programming stand-point, you can treat your "third" list as an entirely new one (even though it contains the same elements as the first).

from an under-the-cover implementation standpoint, it may be that the system is smart enough to know to reuse memory from the first list on the third assignment; i can't immediately think of an efficient way that might work, though, with the code as it's currently written.

so, at the third assignment:

- the first list might still be around
- it's still going to be, from a programming point of view, presented to you as an entirely new list
- it's possible, but very unlikely, that the system, under the covers, knows/is able to optimize memory use well enough to reuse the memory from the first assignment. most likely, unless referenced elsewhere, that first list is garbage collected/will be garbage collected.

---

**NOTE**

Based on @PascalCuoq's answer below, and some experimentation:

The behavior is quite different if you're defining the variables as top-level variables. The  OCaml garbage collector treats top level declarations as (permanent?) garbage collection roots -  so they won't be GCed even if there are no longer reachable from running code.

So, if the above example is executed at the top level, there will be three different "`l`"'s in memory, none of which will be garbage collected.

Comment: (References in the general sense, i.e., any other ways to access the value.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please see my edit, sorry for extra question.

Comment: `let l = [1;2;3;4]` is not an assignment and I wouldn't be too sure that the list is released until I had found a way to verify it.

Comment: I was confused. So in toplevel, it won't be GCed. But if I run it as a native, it will?

Answer (score 4):

Not in the OCaml toplevel, defining a new value `l` does not free the previous `l`, which (as far as I remember the implementation) lives forever. It doesn't matter because it is a constant and only takes space proportional to the source code that engendered it, like binary code does.

```
$ rlwrap ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# let l = [ 1 ] ;;
val l : int list = [1]
# let w = Weak.create 1 ;;
val w : '_a Weak.t = <abstr>
# Weak.set w 0 (Some l) ;;
- : unit = ()
# Gc.full_major () ;;
- : unit = ()
# Weak.check w 0 ;;
- : bool = true
#
```

This `true` [means](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora089.html) that `l` still lives in memory.

```
# let l = [ 2 ] ;;
val l : int list = [2]
# Weak.check w 0 ;;
- : bool = true
# Gc.full_major () ;;
- : unit = ()
# Weak.check w 0 ;;
- : bool = true
#
```

And it still does not, although it is not “reachable” for a fine definition of reachable (not the definition the GC uses).

Neither compiler frees the original `l` either:

```
$ cat t.ml
let l = [ 1 ] ;;
let w = Weak.create 1 ;;
Weak.set w 0 (Some l) ;;
Gc.full_major () ;;
Printf.printf "%B\n" (Weak.check w 0) ;;
let l = [ 2 ] ;;
Printf.printf "%B\n" (Weak.check w 0) ;;
Gc.full_major () ;;
Printf.printf "%B\n" (Weak.check w 0) ;;
$ ocamlc t.ml
$ ./a.out 
true
true
true
$ ocamlopt t.ml
$ ./a.out 
true
true
true
```

Another example of the GC's definition of “reachability” being more approximative than the definition one might like is:

```
let g () = Gc.full_major ()

let f () = let l = [ 1 ] in (* do something with l; *) g(); 1
```

At the point when `g` is executed (called from `f`), the value `l` is no longer reachable (for a fine definition of reachable) and could be garbage-collected. It won't be because it is still referenced from the stack. The GC, with its coarse notion of reachable, will only be able to free it after `f` has terminated.

Comment: If the context is in a ml file, compiled and run, then is what @blueberryfields answered correct?

Comment: @PascalCuoq that looks like an implementation/version specific quirk

Comment: @blueberryfields It has been this way since caml-light, before there were weak pointers to observe that that was what happened. Which “implementation/version” do you claim does not have the “quirk”?

Comment: In your test, is that possible that GC hasn't got chance to free it yet? I wrote in my question, the context is `in an long run ml file`

Comment: @JacksonTale Please see the definition of `Gc.full_major`. http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Gc.html

Comment: ah, I didn't know you can force GC to free immediately.

Comment: @PascalCuoq if this behavior exists in the latest release of the core ocaml implementation, i would open a bug against it.

Comment: @blueberryfields You might get a better explanation by asking in a mailing list why things are this way. Your bug will only be closed as “Works as designed / No change required”.

Comment: oh wow. interesting. this is only at the top (global) level, right?

Comment: @blueberryfields Yes. A function's local variables are allocated to registers and the register allocation mechanism in the native compiler re-uses registers, thus making it visible to the GC that some values are no longer reachable. I temporarily had an example in my answer that showed one couldn't be too impatient for local variables, but I removed it since it only applied to bytecode compilation.